# Android ImageView not working with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

When messing around with my app, I thought giving the user a way to zoom in and out of a particular `ImageViews` was a necessary function to include.

So I went on my way and added in a `ZoomControls` component below the image.

The `ImageView` I am trying to Zoom in and out using `ZoomControls` is actually 8 seperate `ImageViews` inside a `FrameLayout` (to layer the images on top of each other). The `FrameLayout` is then inside a `ScrollView`, and the `ScrollView` is inside of a `HorizontalScrollView`. This allows for scrolling in up-down-left-right.

All of that works fine. But add in the `ZoomControls` and zoom the 8 images in, and the `ImageViews` do as their told and zoom in or out but when I try to scroll left-right-top-down, I either have a quick halt or no interaction at all when I know their is plenty more of Image left to view.

I think this may have to do with my XML hierarchy...
But also may be the way I am zooming.
Here's the code...

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout_main" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="#07000000" >

        <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#222222"> 

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_2" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_3"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible" />       

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_4"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_info"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_5"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_6"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_7"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_legend"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />

    </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
 </HorizontalScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry pasting code straight in messes up alignment. Heres the code controlling the ZoomControl:

```
private void handleZoomControls() {
    zoomControls_Radar.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            float x = imageview_1.getScaleX();
            float y = imageview_1.getScaleY();

            imageview_1.setScaleX((float) (x + .5));
            imageview_1.setScaleY((float) (y + .5));

            imageview_2.setScaleX((float) (x + .5));
            imageview_2.setScaleY((float) (y + .5));

            imageview_3.setScaleX((float) (x + .5));
            imageview_3.setScaleY((float) (y + .5));

            imageview_4.setScaleX((float) (x + .5));
            imageview_4.setScaleY((float) (y + .5));

            imageview_5.setScaleX((float) (x + .5));
            imageview_5.setScaleY((float) (y + .5));

            imageview_6.setScaleX((float) (x + .5));
            imageview_6.setScaleY((float) (y + .5));'

            imageview_7.setScaleX((float) (x + .5));
            imageview_7.setScaleY((float) (y + .5));

            imageview_8.setScaleX((float) (x + .5));
            imageview_8.setScaleY((float) (y + .5));

        }
    });

    zoomControls_Radar.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            float x = imageview_1.getScaleX();
            float y = imageview_1.getScaleY();

            imageview_1.setScaleX((float) (x - .5));
            imageview_1.setScaleY((float) (y - .5));

            imageview_2.setScaleX((float) (x - .5));
            imageview_2.setScaleY((float) (y - .5));

            imageview_3.setScaleX((float) (x - .5));
            imageview_3.setScaleY((float) (y - .5));

            imageview_4.setScaleX((float) (x - .5));
            imageview_4.setScaleY((float) (y - .5));

            imageview_5.setScaleX((float) (x - .5));
            imageview_5.setScaleY((float) (y - .5));

            imageview_6.setScaleX((float) (x - .5));
            imageview_6.setScaleY((float) (y - .5));'

            imageview_7.setScaleX((float) (x - .5));
            imageview_7.setScaleY((float) (y - .5));

            imageview_8.setScaleX((float) (x - .5));
            imageview_8.setScaleY((float) (y - .5));
        }
    });
```

All the images are the same size so thats why I only collect the size of one `ImageView`.

Comment: try adding this `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` property in your imageview in xml layout file.

Comment: I added it to all 8 imageviews and am still receiving the same result. Thanks for the suggestion though